# Altering text of links, then clicking on them in Ruby with Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I managed to fill out a form with Mechanize and get a list of links.
Part of the result looks like:

```
[
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "View" "/cgi-bin/dcdev/forms/C00508200/800329/">,
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "View" "/cgi-bin/dcdev/forms/C00487363/800634/">,
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "View" "/cgi-bin/dcdev/forms/C00498097/800463/">
]
```

I haven't been able to figure out what's next.

1. The pages that I need to scrape are not those links, but rather have `/sa/ALL` at the end of the links, for example: `/cgi-bin/dcdev/forms/C00508200/800329/sa/ALL`. How can I add `sa/ALL` to the end of each link?
2. Then, how can I click on each corrected link, and save the resulting page? A loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
page.links.each do |link|
  agent.get(link.href + 'sa/ALL').save
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you fish...

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="/cgi-bin/dcdev/forms/C00508200/800329/">
    <a href="/cgi-bin/dcdev/forms/C00487363/800634/">
    <a href="/cgi-bin/dcdev/forms/C00498097/800463/">
  </body>
</html>
EOT

hrefs = doc.search('a').map{ |a| a['href'] + '/sa/ALL' }
```

Mechanize uses Nokogiri internally for its HTML parser. You can gain access to the `doc` Mechanize uses with something like:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.example.net')
```

Proof we're dealing with a Nokogiri document:

```
page.parser.class # => Nokogiri::HTML::Document < Nokogiri::XML::Document
```

Get links in the page for manipulation:

```
page.parser.search('a').map(&:to_html)
```

Which returns:

```
[
    [ 0] "<a href=\"/\"><img src=\"/_img/iana-logo-pageheader.png\" alt=\"Homepage\"></a>",
    [ 1] "<a href=\"/domains/\">Domains</a>",
    [ 2] "<a href=\"/numbers/\">Numbers</a>",
    [ 3] "<a href=\"/protocols/\">Protocols</a>",
    [ 4] "<a href=\"/about/\">About IANA</a>",
    [ 5] "<a href=\"/go/rfc2606\">RFC 2606</a>",
    [ 6] "<a href=\"/about/\">About</a>",
    [ 7] "<a href=\"/about/presentations/\">Presentations</a>",
    [ 8] "<a href=\"/about/performance/\">Performance</a>",
    [ 9] "<a href=\"/reports/\">Reports</a>",
    [10] "<a href=\"/domains/\">Domains</a>",
    [11] "<a href=\"/domains/root/\">Root Zone</a>",
    [12] "<a href=\"/domains/int/\">.INT</a>",
    [13] "<a href=\"/domains/arpa/\">.ARPA</a>",
    [14] "<a href=\"/domains/idn-tables/\">IDN Repository</a>",
    [15] "<a href=\"/protocols/\">Protocols</a>",
    [16] "<a href=\"/numbers/\">Number Resources</a>",
    [17] "<a href=\"/abuse/\">Abuse Information</a>",
    [18] "<a href=\"http://www.icann.org/\">Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers</a>",
    [19] "<a href=\"mailto:iana@iana.org?subject=General%20website%20feedback\">iana@iana.org</a>"
]
```

Grabbing and munging them:

```
links = page.parser.search('a').map{ |a| a['href'] + 'sa/ALL' }
[
    [ 0] "/sa/ALL",
    [ 1] "/domains/sa/ALL",
    [ 2] "/numbers/sa/ALL",
    [ 3] "/protocols/sa/ALL",
    [ 4] "/about/sa/ALL",
    [ 5] "/go/rfc2606sa/ALL",
    [ 6] "/about/sa/ALL",
    [ 7] "/about/presentations/sa/ALL",
    [ 8] "/about/performance/sa/ALL",
    [ 9] "/reports/sa/ALL",
    [10] "/domains/sa/ALL",
    [11] "/domains/root/sa/ALL",
    [12] "/domains/int/sa/ALL",
    [13] "/domains/arpa/sa/ALL",
    [14] "/domains/idn-tables/sa/ALL",
    [15] "/protocols/sa/ALL",
    [16] "/numbers/sa/ALL",
    [17] "/abuse/sa/ALL",
    [18] "http://www.icann.org/sa/ALL",
    [19] "mailto:iana@iana.org?subject=General%20website%20feedbacksa/ALL"
]
```

Which links to apply your munging to is for you to determine and how to re-get them is an exercise for you.

Comment: Thanks, this worked well, but I had trouble figuring out how to further manipulate the 'search' criteria. My criteria, as you can probably see above, is 'a' and text='View'. I'll keep trying, though!